# Fermat's Last Theorem (Case n = 3) Question

Tags: number-theory

A very simple question.

We all know that there are no solutions to $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$ for integer $x$, $y$ and $z$, $xyz\neq 0$, but are rational $x$, $y$ and $z$ possible?  Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: clearly you mean without $(0,0,0), (1,0,0)$ etc.

Comment: Yes of course that was implied.

Comment: @KyleGannon, are you sure about $(1, 0, 0)$ being a solution? Clearly you mean $(1, 0, 1)$.

Comment: @chiru Clearly you mean $(0, 1, 1)$.

Comment: [This question got 24 upvotes and 3 stars](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Paris_Tuileries_Garden_Facepalm_statue.jpg/320px-Paris_Tuileries_Garden_Facepalm_statue.jpg).

Answer (score 61):

No: multiplying any rational solution by the product of their denominators, say, would yield an integer solution.

Comment: @Proxima if you feel your question is answered satisfactorily, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the it. This is better than saying thanks since it gives some reputation to the answerer and shows that the question is completed.

Answer (score 39):

No, because if $x=\frac{a}{b}$, $y=\frac{c}{d}$, and $z=\frac{e}{f}$ were rational solutions, so that
$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^3+\left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^3=\left(\frac{e}{f}\right)^3,$$
then there would be an integer solution
$$(adf)^3+(bcf)^3=(bde)^3$$
(edit: this is just writing out the details of Did's answer)

Comment: Yes thanks too.